# Cannot save data in Scala, cannot mkdir error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Scala in Apache Spark. I am very new to the platform. I cannot save a collection to file using the following code:

```
val x = sc.parallelize(Array(2,4,1))
x.saveAsTextFile("/temp/demo")
```

Comment: It's usually '/tmp' not '/temp', in case that's the problem?

Comment: yeah that was the only problem I think it is working now thank you very much @Rup

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a problem about permissions.
Try to write to a directory you have write permissions, e.g. your home.

Comment: your answer was helpful too @sympho410 I am able to write in other directory  thanks a lot